# Bootstrap modal not working - Nothing showing up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I entered this code, but nothing is coming up:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign me up!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...             
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is just html, where is the javascript?

Comment: It's just the one from Bootstrap v3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modals don't show up on their own... They need to be called. Somewhere in some Javascript code you need to implement the following:

```
$("#showModal").modal("show");
```

And that will make it show up. For example, either in a ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#showModal").modal("show");
});
```

Or in a function that gets called by an event:

```
function showModal(){
  $("#showModal").modal("show");
}
```

Then have a button:

```
<button onclick="showModal()">Click Me!</button>
```

If you need more help or other examples, check out the documentation on how modals work here:

[Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: No problem. Be sure to upvote and select as an answer so others can benefit from this as well. Cheers!

Comment: Can't upvote yet - not enough reputation, sorry.. but did  "accept" it. Also, is it alright if I ask you another thing?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, generally, you don't ask new questions in the comments, you make a new question. If it's something quick and related to this issue, then feel free to ask for some clarification.

Comment: Yes, I posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626101/multiple-bootstrap-modals-new-to-this :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a method to trigger the dialog (e.g. a button click), and a call to .modal.('show') method on the actual modal div.

You can read this article to get a more comprehensive overview of Bootstrap modals, along with some demo examples: [Understanding boostrap modals](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-modals/)

```js
$('#clickme').click(function(e) {
    $('#showModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="modal fade" id="showModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Sign me up!</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<button id="clickme" class="btn btn-info">Click Me</button>
```