# Multiple bootstrap modals in a page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a bootstrap modal - it's working fine. But when I want to use a modal somewhere else in my site it overwrites the other modal.

Which part of the code do I need to change? And do I have to add like thousands of extra code to javascript for each modal, or can I make a group code?

Thanks!

I added this:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(e) {
$('#showModal').modal('show');


<script>
    function showModal(){
        $("#showModal").modal("show");
     }
</script>
```

and:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> 
                <h4 class="modal-title">Sign me up!</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: Are you using the same ID for multiple elements? As you can see from the Bootstrap docs page, having more than one modal in a page is not an issue.

Comment: No, I'm using different ID's

Comment: Then it's not at all clear what the problem is from what you've show. Please show a more complete code sample or a demo of the problem. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: As you can see here, using multiple (even simultaneous) modals isn't a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5g2zmu33

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do this. Bootstrap's modal is not designed to support that. Its own documentation says

> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

It should have said "a lot of custom code". For instance, BS modals use a class on the `body` element, that is removed when it closed. Therefore, closing a second modal will also hide the first. Then you need special code to detect that a modal was previously open and restore the class on the body. It's much more trouble than it's worth.

Instead, use a "poor man's modal" for the second modal, just an absolutely positioned div you pop up somewhere. You don't need the overlay covering the screen anyway since it's already there from the first modal.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to have multiple simultaneous modals. In any case, you *can* use simultaneous modals as long as they're not nested.

Comment: It sounded to me like that's exactly what the OP wanted. He says a second modal "overwrites" the first modal, which of course would not happen if he was opening them one at a time. So until he says otherwise it's a good assumption that he wants to open multiple modals at the same time--I don't know what you mean by "nested"--do you mean in the HTML sense? Assuming that's correct, it is not correct to say that you can use "simultaneous modals". BS modals make assumptions throughout that there is exactly one modal open at any time, such as the class on the body I mentioned.

Comment: I've used overlaying Bootstrap modals in a production setting. There's no problem doing so other than the doubling of the mask, which isn't really a problem. The only requirement is that the modal markup not be nested. Making them siblings in the DOM is a good approach. 

You may be right about the OP's needs. It's not clear. Just sharing my viewpoint.

Comment: I know it says not to say something like: thanks, but really thank you very much! @isherwood